# Запись имен файлов из директории в массив СИ

Tags: c, массивы

Нужно записать все имена файлов из директории в массив для дальнейшего переименования их по определенному шаблону, как это можно реализовать?

```
int main (int argc, char *argv []) {
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
struct dirent *ent;
DIR *dir;
const char *directory;
char *OldFileName[255];
char NewFileName[]="File";

directory=argv[1];
dir=opendir(directory);
int i=0;
while ((ent=readdir(dir)) != false) {
OldFileName[i]=ent->d_name;
if(rename(OldFileName[i],NewFileName)==0)
{
printf("переименованно");
}
i++;
}

closedir(dir);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: В Си нет собственного интерфейса для получения списка файлов в каталоге. Для этого нужно использовать API ОС (например, `readdir()`) или сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Код компилируется, непонятен ваш вопрос.

Comment: компилируется но не переименовывает файлы

Comment: Имя файла нужно записывать с полным путём. Может быть в этом и вся проблема.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, или перейти на с++ :) Если это возможно.

Answer (score 0):

readdir возвращает ссылку на структуру dirent. Если закончился список файлов, то NULL, а не false. Второе для меня не понятно, зачем массив OldFileName. Да и 255, как то не серьезно для списка фалов в каталоге (папке). Если закончится  размерность будет выход за границу массива и ошибка Segmentation fault. Так что массив тут не нужен. И еще, я бы проверил код возврата из opendir. Может быть опять же NULL

Comment: А если массив не нужен то как тогда запоминать имена фалов и переименовывать их?

Comment: зачем запоминать? Переименовал и все. Это же только для одного файла СЕЙЧАС, СИЮ МИНУТУ. Не вижу задачи хранить где то